# adding a rectangle to .tif file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Suppose you have .tif file which has 14 pages (multi image tif). I'd like to draw a rectangle on a specific place on a specific page. However, below example does not paste my img which I drew with ImageDraw anywhere on the second page. Where am I failing this?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('tiffile.tif')

for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
    if i == 1:
        height = width = 800
        img = Image.new('RGB', (height, width), (255, 0, 0))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
        page.paste(img, (0,0))
        

im.save('tiffile_b.tif', save_all=True)
```

Comment: Why the `paste` step? Why not `ImageDraw.Draw()` directly onto `page`?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, thought i had to create a new image and paste it onto that page, but that might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @AKX suggested there's no need to create a new image on to paste it onto the current page. Instead draw the rectangle on that page. However, I had to save all the pages in a list and then create a new .tif file out of the new pages in the list.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('tiffile.tif')

frames=[]
for i, page in enumerate(ImageSequence.Iterator(im)):
    page = page.copy()
    if i == 1:
        box = (0, 590, 2272, 2570)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(page)
        draw.rectangle(box, outline=(0), fill=(250))
    frames.append(page)
            
frames[0].save('testfile_b.tif', save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:])
```

Comment: In the .tif image I open, how to I specify with a rectangle the area I want to process? I do not want to put the rectangle a priori, but in "real time" as I examine the image and to help my code do process on the specific space bounded by the rectangle.... By the way I use PyQt and OpenCV.